# Exception policy for "finally" in C++

Tags: c++, exception, raii, finally

Consider the class `finally`, running arbitrary user code in destructor.

Here's the most minimal implementation (without forwarding, auxiliary function, etc.):

```
template<typename Func>
class finally
{
public:
    finally(Func f) : f_(f) {}
    ~finally() { f_(); }

private:
    Func f_;
};
```

The question is: how exceptions in user code should be treated? .

Here are the variants I could think of, which of them do you think is better, assuming the class is supposed to be used in broad range of situations?

**1)** Do nothing. `~finally() /*noexcept*/ { f_(); }`

Destructor of `finally` is implicitly `noexcept`, so any exception in user code leads to `terminate()`.
User must think every time about noexceptness of his code and guard it manually with try/catch if it throws.

**2)** Completely transparent destructor. `~finally() noexcept(f_()) { f_(); }`

Destructor of `finally` is conditionally `noexcept`, so any exception is passed through and `terminate()` is called only if it happens during stack unwinding.
User should probably think about stack unwinding scenarios, but calling `terminate()` in such situations may be the right decision by default.

**3)** Catch all exceptions in destructor. `~finally() { try { f_(); } catch (...) {} }`

Classic destructor not throwing anything.
Restricts user's capabilities of error checking with exceptions, but with good intend. Probably less efficient because of try/catch block. User doesn't have to think about anything.

**3+)** (Probably) optimized 3), uses specialization/SFINAE to omit try/catch block if `f_()` is `noexcept`.

May redundantly enclose C functions like `fclose(FILE*)` in try/catch block since they are not noexcept, but such functions are probably not used  with finally directly, but through lambdas, which also can be easily not marked as `noexcept` out of forgetfulness.

**4)** Static assertion that `f_()` is noexcept.

The user have to explicitly mark his code as `noexcept` every time, then catching or not catching exceptions is his concern. Again restricts user's capabilities of error checking with exceptions, but with good intend.

**4+)** 4) plus some specialization of finally (maybe even another separate class template) with semantics of 2) which is free of the assertion, but must be used explicitly.

Comment: I personally would let the exception just escape, as if the user had written f_(); at the point of exit... but you will get more opinions than you gave choices.

Comment: RAII should be responsible for whatever this `finally` is being used for.

Comment: It's not the most minimal because it violates the rule of three. No one greens non-r3 code in a code review, right?

Comment: @sftrabbit: I somehow have the feeling that this finally is an application of raii

Comment: @PlasmaHH But the objects that are being cleaned up by `finally` should be cleaning themselves up in their destructors.

Comment: it seems you're trying to reimplement a scope-exit library you should take a look at [boost scope exit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: To add to what sftrabbit said: if you are using `fclose` with this, you are doing it wrong. Write a class that closes your files in the destructor (there is even prior art in the standard library for this, in the form of `fstream`). No point in going only halfway with RAII.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes. I omitted deleted copy constructor/assignment (ust like everything else) because they are not related to the question. This finally is not a real usable class, but just an illustration for the question.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Of course, it's possible to write a separate RAII class for each pair like fopen/fclose, but finally is also an option.

Comment: @user2665887 it is... but it's bad practice, in C++ you should always wrap a resource in an RAII wrapper to ensure that specific resource gets closed appropriately.

Comment: Small addition: [Boost.ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) uses variant 1) as I understand

Comment: Option 5) Try-catch with logging. Doesn't abort the program, but leaves a trace of the error.

I personally use noexcept in debug builds (abort if unexpected condition is unhandled), and try-catch-log in builds sent to customers, since an application as a whole can usually carry on fine.